# Deploying Docusaurus V2 on GitHub Pages with GIT_USER=<github-username> yarn deploy prints "-bash: No such file"

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docusaurus

I can't find any applicable information on this and would appreciate some help:

I am trying to deploy a Docusaurus V2 site to GitHub pages using the WSL command line.
I'm using the `GIT_USER=<github_username> yarn deploy` command. This doesn't work and prints `-bash: github_username: No such file or directory.`

The github_username is not a file or directory, from what I understand it's a way to authenticate with GitHub. Here are the docs: https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment

Thank you in advance for any pointers on this!

Edit: Forgot to include = in the commands here. I used the command with the equal sign and it still returns this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an outdated Node version. Once I updated it everything worked!